How do I get rid of double edges/verticies?
This might be a dumb question, but my models always seem to have edges and vertices stacked on top of each other without me even adding a bevel, loop cuts or anything.  I know I can merge by distance but that doesn't seem to work for me, especially with the edges.  I'm just wondering if there's a quick way to get rid of all these duplicate edges.
The edges I think I wan't beveled:

The beveled result, note the black edges:

I'm trying to bevel the tread of this shoe, and i've already merged vertices by distance just enough so that my mesh isn't altered, but when I go to bevel, new unselected edges are appearing, making my bevel unsatisfactory.  I think part of the problem could be me manually filling faces from added vertices and not making sure they're actually connected to the mesh, but not sure.

hello maybe share a part of your object where it happens

I resolved my issue. It turned out that the problem was simply that not all the faces were connected.
